# Find the sum of all 4 digit numbers which are formed by the digits 1,2,5,6?

Tags: permutations

> I have researched and found 2 approaches but haven't understood both.Can anyone explain it clearly or probably with any real world example?

Approach 1

Four digit numbers $ = 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 = 24$ ways we can form a four digit number. Since it's a 4 digit number, each digit will appear $6= 24/4$ times in each of units, tens, hundreds, and thousands place. Therefore, the sum of digits in the units place is $6(1+2+5+6)=84$.

Why they are adding $1+2+5+6$?

Similarly sum of digits at tens,hundreds,thousands place is $84$

Required sum of all numbers $= 84+ 84 \cdot 10+ 84 \cdot 100+ 84 \cdot 1000=93324$

Approach 2

I found it here:

[Find the sum of all 4-digit numbers formed by using digits 0, 2, 3, 5 and 8?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/479723/find-the-sum-of-all-4-digit-numbers-formed-by-using-digits-0-2-3-5-and-8)

Though I have understood the 2 approaches, I am not able to understand the question.

Comment: Consider that 123+456 = 153+426 = 156+423 = ... simply by swapping hundreds, tens, unit digits.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this answer I presume that all digits $1,2,5,6$ must be present in the number.

There are $4!=24$ such numbers.

We can index them with $i=1,\dots,24$
and write each of them as $$n_{i}=a_{i}+10b_{i}+100c_{i}+1000d_{i}$$
where $\left\{ a_{i},b_{i},c_{i},d_{i}\right\}=\{1,2,5,6\} $

Then $$\sum_{i=1}^{24}n_{i}=\sum_{i=1}^{24}a_{i}+10\sum_{i=1}^{24}b_{i}+100\sum_{i=1}^{24}c_{i}+1000\sum_{i=1}^{24}d_{i}$$

$\left\{ i\mid a_{i}=1\right\} $, $\left\{ i\mid a_{i}=2\right\} $,
$\left\{ i\mid a_{i}=5\right\} $ and $\left\{ i\mid a_{i}=6\right\} $
have equal cardinality $\frac{24}4=6$ so: $$\sum_{i=1}^{24}a_{i}=6.1+6.2+6.5+6.6=6(1+2+5+6)=84$$

This can also be applied for $b,c$ and $d$ and finally we find:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{24}n_{i}=84+10.84+100.84+1000.84=1111.84=93324$$

Does this really answers your question? If not, then please let me know.

Comment: No,I am afraid i haven't understood the question.Approach are nearly the same.I can calculate How many 4 digit numbers but i cannot calculate sum of all 4 digit numbers because i am not able to think what they mean by sum of all 4 digit numbers.

Comment: Let it be $2$-digit numbers formed by $3$ and $6$. Then there are two: $36$ and $63$. The sum of all these numbers is then $36+63$.

Answer (score 1):

For getting the sum of 4 digits numbers we can apply the formula as follows:-

$(\text{sum of given digits}) \times 1~1~1~1\cdots ~n ~(\text{given number of digits}) \times (\text{number of digits}-1)!$

eg:- to find the sum of $~4~$ digits using $~2 , ~3 , ~4 , ~5~$

sol:-  $$(2+3+4+5) \times (1111)\times ( 4-1 )!$$
     $$= (14 ) \times ( 1111 ) \times ( 3! )$$
    $$  = 14 \times 1111 \times 6$$
      $$= 93324$$

Answer (score 0):

We can solve by

Average of the 'smallest number formed by all digits' and 'biggest number formed by all digits'} * {Number of given digits}!

i.e for 0,2,3,5,8

Smallest number formed by using all these digits = 20358
Biggest number formed by using all these digits = 85320

Average = (20358+85320)/2
        =  52839
So Answer to the given question is = 52839*5!
                                   = **6340680**

Answer (score 0):

for lets say 4 digit : a,b,c and d : to arrange in 4 places without repetition is 4!
So each digit appears 24/4=6 times in a position - 1st, 10th, 100th and 1000th position.
**So sum of all digits in each position is same = 6*(a+b+c+d).**
let say the sum is a two digit number say **ef**. So now the last digit of 1st position is **f**. The sum of 10th position is **ef** again but with the carry from 1st position **e**. Similarly sum of 100th position is **ef+carry of 10th position**. And so on for 1000th position.

Answer (score 0):

It has a direct formula, i.e. **when there are n different digits and sum of all n digit no formed by these digits is** =

$$(\text{sum of all n digits)} \times (111...n times) \times \text{n-1}!$$

---

It is derived by this method:

Method of expansion

Ex:         $284 = 200 + 80 + 4$

Suppose a digit ‘a’ (one of the n digit) when placed at unit place it forms (n-1)! combinations then its digits' sum when it appears at unit place = $$(n-1)! \times 1 \times \text{a}$$

Similarly, when it appears at tens place, then sum of its digits' is =
$$(n-1)! \times 10 \times \text{a}$$

.

.

Similarly, when it appears at $n^{th}$ place , then sum of its digits' is=
$$(n-1)! \times 1000..\text{n times} \times \text{a}$$

Now, sum of all a appeared ( with their values) =

Again now sum of all no formed by permutations =
Sum of all the numbers appeared like ‘a’ with their values =
$$(n-1)! \times 1111..\text{n times} \times \text{sum of all n numbers}$$

---

Therefore, our ans for the question as follows:

For getting the sum of 4 digits numbers we can apply the formula as follows:-

$(\text{sum of given digits}) \times 1~1~1~1\cdots ~n ~(\text{given number of digits}) \times (\text{number of digits}-1)!$

eg:- to find the sum of $~4~$ digits using $~2 , ~3 , ~4 , ~5~$

sol:-  $$(2+3+4+5) \times (1111)\times ( 4-1 )!$$
$$= 93324$$