# Find the sum of all 5 digit numbers formed using $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

**Given solution**

The sum of all the numbers is
$10 \times 24 \times 10^4 + 10 \times 18 \times 10^3 + 10 \times 18 \times 10^2 + 10 \times 18 \times 10 + 10 \times 18 \times 1. $

**My work**

Clearly, the number of 5 digit numbers that can be formed is
$$4\times 5\times 5 \times 5 \times 5$$
$$=2500$$

The first 5 digit number is $10000$

So sum of the numbers should be
$$S=\frac {1250}{2} (20000 + 2499)$$
$$=14061875$$

But given answer is $2599980$

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120326/discussion-on-question-by-aditya-find-the-sum-of-all-5-digit-numbers-formed-usi).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trying to collate comments:

First, it is important to understand what the question is asking.  The problem wants you to find the sum of all numbers in the set $\{x~:~x~\text{is a five digit number with nonrepeating digits whose digits all come from the set }\{0,1,2,3,4\}\}$.

That is to say, it is asking for you to evaluate $$10234 + 10243 + 10324 + 10342 + 10423 + 10432 + 12034 + 12043 + 12304 + 12340 + 13024 + \dots + 43012 + 43021 + 43201 + 43210$$

This is a sum of several five-digit numbers.  You ask "*what is wrong with my solution.*"  What is wrong is that you attempted to use a formula regarding a sum of terms in an arithmetic progression however the terms in this sum are not in an arithmetic progression.

"*I don't know whether the question is asking for sum of digits or sum of numbers formed by the digits*"

The question is asking for sum of numbers formed by the digits, however through some clever reorganization of our thought process we can accomplish this by looking at digits individually.

---

Next, some groundwork reminding you how to add...

Recall that if we want to add two numbers, for example $12340 + 31420$ we can do this by adding the respective positions together...  That is to say, $\color{red}{1}\color{blue}{2}\color{green}{3}\color{purple}{4}0 + \color{red}{3}\color{blue}{1}\color{green}{4}\color{purple}{2}0$ we add the red digits together $\color{red}{1}+\color{red}{3}=\color{red}{4}$, we add the blue digits together, $\color{blue}{2}+\color{blue}{1}=\color{blue}{3}$ etc...  Our result is $\color{red}{4}\color{blue}{3}\color{green}{7}\color{purple}{6}0$

Formally, what happened here was that $12340$ can be interpreted as $1\cdot 10^4 + 2\cdot 10^3 + 3\cdot 10^2 + 4\cdot 10^1 + 0\cdot 10^0$.  Similarly $31420$ can be broken up.  We combined like terms, having added all of the terms who were multiples of $10^4$ together, adding all those who were multiples of $10^3$ together, etc...

The same principle works when adding *many* numbers together... however we might normally want to keep track of "carry-over digits" like how $\color{red}{1}\color{blue}{8}+\color{red}{1}\color{blue}{8} = 36$ and not $\color{red}{2}\color{blue}{16}$.  So, we can't just concatenate the results of the separate additions... but that doesn't mean that the way of thinking of this is flawed... here we do indeed have $18+18 = (1\cdot 10 + 8) + (1\cdot 10 + 8) = (1 + 1)\cdot 10 + (8 +8)$, that is still perfectly correct.

"*Your answer seems to calculate sum of digits (from my perspective)*"  While yes, we did add digits individually, we did so keeping track of which digit place they originated from by keeping the $10^4$ and $10^3$ and such terms with them as well...

Now... we take this idea but apply it on a much grander scale.

---

In our overall grand sum, there are as mentioned *several* five digit numbers.  How many?  $4\cdot 4!$, seen by routine application of counting principles.  (*Pick the first digit, noting it may not be zero.  Then pick the second digit noting it can't be what was picked for the first, then pick the third digit, etc... for $4\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1$ total outcomes*)

Now... we organize our thoughts as alluded to by thinking of $10234$ as $1\cdot 10^4 + 0\cdot 10^3 + 2\cdot 10^2 + 3\cdot 10^1 + 4$, we think of $10243$ as $1\cdot 10^4 + 0\cdot 10^3 + 2\cdot 10^2 + 4\cdot 10^1 + 3$ etc...

Now... we may freely rearrange terms in the sum, moving all of the $10^4$ terms together, then moving all of the $10^3$ terms together, all of the $10^2$ terms together, and so on and we evaluate each of these separately.

Factoring out each of the $10^4$'s $10^3$'s etc... after rearranging and sorting within each parenthetical phrase we now have a sum which looks like:

$$(1+1+1+\dots+2+2+\dots + 3+3+\dots +4+4+\dots)\cdot 10^4 + (0+0+\dots+1+1+\dots+2+2+\dots+3+3+\dots+4+4+\dots)\cdot 10^3 + \dots + (0+0+\dots+1+1+\dots+2+2+\dots+3+3+\dots+4+4+\dots)$$

The challenge here is that it is difficult at a glance to evaluate the sums of these parentheses without more information... but we have more information.  Specifically, we know there are $4\cdot 4!$ terms in each of these sums.  Next, we know that $1$'s, $2$'s, $3$'s, and $4$'s each occur the same amount of times as each other within each parentheses... so in that first parentheses a quarter of the numbers being added are $1$, a quarter are $2$, etc...

So, we have the first parenthetical term is  $(\underbrace{1+1+\dots}_{4!~\text{terms}}+\underbrace{2+2+\dots}_{4!~\text{terms}}+\dots)\cdot 10^4$ which simplifies to $4!\cdot (1+2+3+4)\cdot 10^4$

Now, the rest of the parenthetical phrases are all similar to each other.  Like before, there are some number of $1$'s, $2$'s, $3$'s and $4$'s and due to symmetry we know there will be just as many $1$'s as there are $4$'s etc...

However the $0$'s are there in the mix as well.  We count how many times $0$ appears as the $1000$'s digit in the $5$-digit numbers we are counting.  By counting principles, we pick the first digit, the second digit we are forcing to be zero, we then pick the third digit, fourth digit, and fifth digit for a total of $4!$ different numbers with $0$ in the second place.

As such, it follows from symmetry that $3\cdot 3!$ different numbers have a $1$ in the second place, similarly for $2$'s, $3$'s etc...

So, the second parenthetical phrase in the grand sum is:

$$(\underbrace{0+0+0+\dots}_{4!~\text{terms}}+\underbrace{1+1+\dots}_{3\cdot 3!~\text{terms}}+\underbrace{2+2+\dots}_{3\cdot 3!~\text{terms}}+\dots)\cdot 10^3$$

which simplifies as

$$(4!\cdot 0 + 3\cdot 3! \cdot 1 + 3\cdot 3!\cdot 2 + \dots) \cdot 10^3 = 3\cdot 3!\cdot (1+2+3+4)\cdot 10^3$$

The same analysis holds for the hundreds digits, tens digits, and ones digits.

We have as a final grand total then:

$$10234 + 10243 + 10324 + 10342 + 10423 + 10432 + 12034 + 12043 + 12304 + 12340 + 13024 + \dots + 43012 + 43021 + 43201 + 43210$$

$$=4!\cdot (1+2+3+4)\cdot 10^4 + 3\cdot 3!\cdot (1+2+3+4)\cdot 10^3 + 3\cdot 3!\cdot (1+2+3+4)\cdot 10^2 + 3\cdot 3!\cdot (1+2+3+4)\cdot 10^1 + 3\cdot 3!\cdot (1+2+3+4)$$

$$=24\cdot 10\cdot 10^4 + 18\cdot 10\cdot 1111$$

$$=2599980$$

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be assuming that as you have $2500$ five digit numbers and the first one is $10000$ that the numbers will be *all* the numbers from $10000$ to $12499$.  But you aren't doing all the numbers.  You are only doing the numbers with digits $0,1,2,3,4$ and you skipping the numbers with any digits between $5$-$9$.

This is certainly *not* and arithmetic progression.

But if we designate the $k$th number as $a_k$ and the five digits as $b_{k,0},b_{k,1},...etc.$ then $a_k = 10000b_{k,4} + 1000b_{k,3} + 100b_{k,2} + 10b_{k,1} + b_{k,0}$.

And $\sum a_k = 10000\sum b_{k,4} + 1000\sum b_{k,3} +... etc.$

So it a matter of just calculating the sums of the digits.

For any number with a first digit of $w$ (where $w$ can by $1,2,3,4$) there we $5^4$ numbers begining with $w$.  So  $10000\sum b_{k,4} = 100000(5^4)\cdot 1 + 10000(5^4)\cdot 2 + ... etc= 1000(5^4)(1+2+3+4)$.$.

And for any number with $j$th digit, $j$ not the first digit, there will be $4\cdot 5^3$ numbers with that same digit.

SO hopefully it will be clear that

$\sum a_k = $

$10000\sum b_{k,4} + 1000\sum b_{k,3} +100\sum b_{k,2} + 10\sum b_{k,1} + \sum b_{k,0} =$

$10000\cdot 5^4 (1+2+3+4) + 1000\cdot 4\times 5^3 (0+1+2+3+4) + 100\cdot 4\times 5^3 (0+1+2+3+4)+10\cdot 4\times 5^3 (0+1+2+3+4) + 4\times 5^3 (0+1+2+3+4)=$

$5^4\cdot 100000\cdot 10 + 4\cdot 5^3\cdot 10(1000 + 100 + 10 + 1)=$

$62500000 + 5000\times 1111 = $

$62500000 + 5555000= 68055000$

Which.... doesn't match the answer at all.

.....

So I'm thinking the are asking for numbers with no repetitions.  They use *all* $0,1,2,3,4$ and each exactly once.

In that case:

There are $4!$ numbers that begin with $1,2,3$ or $4$.  And so if you add only what those numbers contribute to the sum, that should be:  $10^4 \times 4! \times (1+2+3+4)$.

And for ever other digit... well, if that digit is $0$ there are $4!$ options for the other $4$ digits.  But if that digit isn't $0$ there are $3$ options for the first digit which can not be $0$ and $3!$ for the remaining digits.  So if we add only what the $k$th digit contributes to the sume we get $10^k (4!\times 0 + 3\cdot 3!(1+2+3+4)) = 10^k(3\cdot 3!(1+2+3+4))$.

So the sum is $(10^4 \cdot 4! + 3\cdot 3!\cdot 1111)(1+2+3+4)=$

$(10^4\cdot 24 + 18\times 1111)\cdot 10 = $

$2400000 + 199980= 2599980$

Comment: Wait aren’t there $4\times 4!$ numbers?

Comment: No.  You used one of the non-zero digits for the current place value.  That leaves the three non-zero choices for the first digit. Now you have the $0$ and two other digits remaining for the remaining three places.  So that is $3\cdot 3!$.

Answer (score 0):

Fresh after morning coffee !

It should be clear that permuting $n$ distinct digits will yield $n!$ number strings, and that each column, by symmetry, will contain $\frac{n!}{n}$ repetitions of each digit.

With leading zeros allowed, one rep of $0,1,2,3,4$ will sum to $10$, and giving place values to each digit,  we will get

sum $= 10\cdot\dfrac{5!}5(10^4+10^3+10^2+10^1+10^0) = 10\cdot\frac{5!}5(11111)$

But we need to eliminate leading zeroes, and for this we simply subtract the sum of a $4$ digit number using the distinct digits ${1,2,3,4}$
to finally get

$\left[10\cdot\frac{5!}5(11111)\right] - \left[10\cdot\frac{4!}4(1111)\right] = \boxed{2599980}$